# How to refer Element using xpath inside multiple <li> that in turn contains <a> tag

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, testng

How can i refer multiple elements present under li tag using xpath?

```
<div id="accordian">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h3 class="classroom"></h3>

           <ul style="display: block;">
                <li><a href="name01">name1</a></li>
                <li><a href="name02">name2</a></li>
                <li><a href="name03">name3</a></li>
                <li><a href="name04">name4</a></li>   
           </ul>

       </li>
```

i am using Selenium Webdriver, I tried following code to refer the element, but it returns a blank value.

```
List<WebElement> listelement=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='accordian']/ul/li/ul/li"));

for(WebElement list: listelement)
{
  System.out.println(list.getText());
}
```

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: Guys, When i am using  `listelement.size()` it returns me value 4, means xpath will not have problem

Comment: Rather `list.getText()` try to get child list element `<a>` and then do a getText() for that element.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<WebElement> list=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='accordian']/ul/li/ul/li"));
```

just add a tag at end of your xpath, that all this will work

```
//div[@id='accordian']/ul/li/ul/li/a"
```

Answer (score 0):

*** This is a comment as I don't have access to Comments section ****

Hi,

Limit xpath till /ul and don't use /li. It will return list and then iterate over the child elements.

```
xpath("//div[@id='accordian']/ul/li/ul")
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt about the Xpath you tried, But below is the way you can achieve it.

```
List<WebElement> list=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='accordian']/ul/li/ul/li"));

System.out.println("No of names present="+ list.size());

    // use of for loop for iteration
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.println(list.get(i).getText());
    }
    System.out.println("-------------------------");
         //use of for each for iteration
        for(WebElement wb: list)
        System.out.println(wb.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

Do getText() on `a` tag elements. I always prefer using css over xpath. So here is my solution,

```
By byCss = By.cssSelector("#accordian>ul>li>ul>li>a");

List<WebElement> listElement = driver.findElements(byCss);

for(WebElement list: listElement)
{
  System.out.println(list.getText());
}
```

Comment: Hi Saifur, I tried your solution, but it prints 4 blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and struggled with it for few days. You can use href tag as well to fetch the elements. Also You can try using 'a' tag. It will be something like this:

```
List<WebElement> listelement=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='accordian']/ul/li/ul/li/a"));

for(WebElement list: listelement) {
  String name= list.getAttribute("href");
  System.out.println(name);
 }
```

Comment: Hi Niti, getAttribute("href") returns links not name. Is there any way to get names?

Comment: Hi, did you try a tag? It is working for me in the xpath tester.

Comment: I used freeformatter-- http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html   These are te snapshots: http://www.imageno.com/thumbs/20150507/taay4auetr1j.jpg http://www.imageno.com/h8tjay9fk51bpic.html

Answer (score 0):

---should be comment, but don't have enough reputation---

I tried your solution on given HTML,

for me it is working fine for chromedriver and firefox.(printing all four values from list)

for InternetExplorer driver i am not able to get values, but it it because listElement.size() is 0

You can try

```
element.getAttribute("value") or elem.getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

to check what is happening here.

Answer (score 0):

swapnil, your code with xpath is working for me, I get all the 4 elements, still you can try this as well

```
  List<WebElement> listElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
  for(WebElement a : listElements){         
      System.out.println(a.getText());
  }
```